# How to access node server from remote machine with in same LAN

Tags: node.js

Suppose if my ip address is : 192.65.35.12. In this machine I'm running node server. I can access the webpages by using this url: `http://localhost:3000/` in the same machine.

But, if I'm trying to access the node server from a remote machine having the ip `192.65.35.11`. It does not work. I used the below url to access the url from the remote machine:
`http://192.65.35.12:3000/`

I'm facing network connectivity issues.

Do, I need to change any settings in node.js for remote access.

Then, how can I access the node server from the remote machine.

Comment: whichOS did you run for node.js app, on windows or linux ?

Comment: on Windows firewall > Advance settting > Inpound rules > Create an inpound rule to allow port 3000 connect from outside to inside.

Comment: configured windows firewall but still I'm unable to access remote machine's node server

Comment: can you ping `192.65.35.12` from  `192.65.35.11` PC ?

Comment: yeah I'm able to ping

Comment: try to `telnet 192.168.35.12 3000` from `192.168.35.11` PC and give me the result

Comment: This what I got after pinging:Pinging 192.65.35.12 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.65.35.12: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.65.35.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.65.35.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.65.35.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.65.35.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 1ms

Comment: how about `telnet`  command

Comment: I'm getting this error through telnet     
 Connecting To 192.65.35.12...Could not open connection to the host, on port [3000]: Connect failed

Comment: this mean, port 3000 is closed, did you configure firewall were correct?

Comment: yes I did it .Had created new inbound rule for 3000 port

Comment: did you run node.js app in daemon mode ? it means you can visit http://192.65.35.12:3000/  on itself `192.168.35.12` and it's up everytime.

Comment: yes.If the nodeserver is up,I can visit using the above url

Answer (score 4):

Use this IP `0.0.0.0` to open your app on all interfaces provided by your computer.

Comment: where should I provide this ?

Comment: Or better yet, use nothing at all. The IP address is optional and defaults to binding on all interfaces.

Comment: @slebetman: True! @dev777: If you use [express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen), you d have to change `app.listen(3000)` to `app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`. __Do not forget to configure the firewall__.

Comment: Actually. Both `app.listen(3000)` and `app.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0')` is correct. The mistake a lot of people make is `app.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1')` which basically says "I don't want this server to be accessible from the network"

Comment: How to configure firewall?

Comment: that s a whole different question. You should make new SO, tell about your OS, and desired port to open. The best is to search as i believe this has been answered a thousand times yet !

Answer (score 3):

On linux server you need to open port for outside client to reach it.

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
$ sudo service iptables restart
```

Then start your server

Comment: Was very helpful. The two last lines wasn't necessary on my machine.